# Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense can't find headers of cmake libraries but project compiles

Tags: c++, cmake, intellisense, visual-studio-2022, qt6

I have a Cmake project which uses Qt6. The project compiles fine although Intellisense can't seem to find the headers for Qt6, giving the error: `File 'QtWidget' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.` Here is the cmake file (slightly simplified):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project ("Project" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui)

file(GLOB_RECURSE ProjectFiles CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "CustomWidgets/*" "Headers/*" "MainWindow/*")

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${ProjectFiles})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui)
```

I have looked around and seen someone suggest that the problem could lie with `find_package` as it doesn't pass the include paths to intellisense(?). I have also tried deleting .vs/

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui)` is what passes the include directories. `Qt6::Widgets` ... are aliases to CMake targets that have dependent settings that are applied via this command. With this said I have no idea why Intellisense is failing here.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170#intellisense-for-cmake-projects)?

Comment: Are you opening the cmake project in visual studio or generating a visual studio project from cmake?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm just opening a cmake project with visual studio. Generating a visual studio solution does make the includes work as normal, although I would prefer to avoid this since then adding new files/folders becomes a pain.